# templated label should be non-visible when content is null but border keeps showing

Tags: wpf, xaml, border

this must be very simple but it's monday morning.. I have a label and overridden the template with a border. when I set statusLabel.Content to null I expect the label to become non-visible but instead the label's border still is. how do I get rid of the border just when statusLabel.Content is null? below is the associated xaml:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image Name="statusImage" 
           Stretch="None"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Margin="20, 20, 0, 0"/>
    <Label Name="statusLabel" 
        Margin="20, 20, 0, 0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:StatusLayer}, Path=StatusTextBackground}"
        FontSize ="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:StatusLayer},  Path=FontSize}"
        FontStyle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:StatusLayer}, Path=FontStyle}"
        FontWeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:StatusLayer}, Path=FontWeight}"
        Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:StatusLayer}, Path=StatusTextForeground}"
        FontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:StatusLayer}, Path=FontFamily}" >
        <Label.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="5">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Label.Template>
    </Label>
</StackPanel>
```

**UPDATE:** thanks for the code in your answers, it showed me that my previous attempts to get the border to disappear failed because the trigger I tested with earlier (not listed in my question code) checked on Value="null" instead of Value="{x:Null}"... DOH! using the correct trigger with setting the visibility on the Label works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Border and the ContentPresenter:

```
Visibility="{TemplateBinding Visibility}"
```

Does it solve the problem?

I doubt it does, but trying can't hurt :p

Otherwise, you need to add a DataTrigger bound to the Content property of the label, and when it is null, set the visibility of the label to Collapsed or Hidden. 
Since the inner control's visibility is now bound to the visibility of the label, everything should disappear.

Comment: thanks! just tested this and it works just as expected, I had to add a trigger for visibility, PS: did you mean <Trigger>?

Comment: Yes, <Trigger> can do it too =) If this solves your problem, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, completely untested:

```
<Label.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Border Name="LabelBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="5">
             <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter ElementName="LabelBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Label.Template>
```

Comment: are the templatebindings for visibility on the border and contentpresenter unnecessary?

Comment: apparently they are because they are lower in the visual tree than Label